# Overriding ansible config with extra vars

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

I define a custom ansible.cfg, and export it as below in the

```
export ANSIBLE_CONFIG="../aws_ansible.cfg"
```

when I run it, this is picked up but when I pass the inventory as an arg, it fails to recognize the arg or take precedence although there is no inventory specified in the `aws_ansible.cfg`.

```
 export ANSIBLE_CONFIG=../aws_ansible.cfg
 ansible-playbook demo.yml -i ./inventories/dev1 --verbose
 Using /projects/demo/aws_ansible.cfg as config file
```

If I specify the inventory within `aws_ansible.cfg` it would work, but I would like to pass it as an argument.

Please advice if also `extra-vars` would take precedence over what are specified in `aws_ansible.cfg`

`aws_ansible.cfg` looks as below

```
[defaults]
; strategy_plugins = ../mitogen/ansible_mitogen/plugins/strategy

private_key_file=~/.ssh/id_rsa
inventory = ./inventories/dev2/hosts
remote_user=ec2-user
host_key_checking = false
filter_plugins = ./filter_plugins
roles_path = ./roles
retry_files_enabled = False

[ssh_connection]

ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=600s -o ControlPath="~/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r"
pipelining = True
```

Comment: For *variables*, [this guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) says `--extra-vars` always wins precedence. [When CLI options exist](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_configuration.html#command-line-options) they always override the config file. What else is in that file?

Comment: I edited the question above

Answer (score 0):

You might want to find out what ansible_inventory_sources are listed.

```
- debug:                                                                                 
    msg: "{{ ansible_inventory_sources }}"
```